# not found the scss file when using styling in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

i want to use the styling in angular for short address in scss files .

i using the styling by this way :

i create a folder in the `src` folder and put the style on that :

[image]

and i go to `angular-cli.json` and i add this :

[image: Image 2]

```
       "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src",
            "src/stylings/",
            "src/stylings/base/",
            "src/stylings/kt-customs/"
          ]
        },
```

and i need to use that in the `style.css` like this way :

```
    @import "custom-form";
@import "custom-buttons";
@import "custom-table";
@import "custom-filter";
@import "kt-customise";
```

but it show me this error :

>
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-3!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--17-1!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
9 │ @import "custom-form";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  E:\MyProject\Ava\PFA\demo\src\styles.scss 9:9  root stylesheet

**how can i solve this problem ????**

Comment: have you found a solution for this? Is it required to include all possible paths in `includePaths`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the import paths you are using in your `style.scss` are wrong. It should be:

```
@import "./stylings/custom-form";
@import "./stylings/custom-buttons";
@import "./stylings/custom-table";
@import "./stylings/custom-filter";
@import "./stylings/kt-customise";
```

You may want to consider changing your `scss` files into scss partials files. That is, renaming both your `scss` files *and* your imports with a leading underscore. e.g. `_custom-form.scss`.

Individual `scss` files are transpiled into individual `css` files. Each `@import` in a css file creates a HTTP request. Which means more css files = more HTTP requests. Importing partials will result in fewer `css` files, and hence, fewer HTTP requests. You may read more on partials here: [SASS Partials](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4).